No PWM output on STM32WLE5
I'm trying to generate PWM output on RAK3172-SIP built with STMWLE5CCU6 without success. My goal is to generate PWM outut on PA8 and PA9, but for the moment I can't generate PWM on one pin...
Here is what I've tried in main.c:
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SubGHz_Phy_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();

  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK){
      Error_Handler();
  }

  while (1)
  {
  }

}

void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure LSE Drive Capability
  */
  HAL_PWR_EnableBkUpAccess();
  __HAL_RCC_LSEDRIVE_CONFIG(RCC_LSEDRIVE_LOW);

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSE|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSEState = RCC_LSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = RCC_MSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_11;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure the SYSCLKSource, HCLK, PCLK1 and PCLK2 clocks dividers
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK3|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLK3Divider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

And in my tim.c:
void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 0 */

    TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

      htim1.Instance = TIM1;
      htim1.Init.Prescaler = 49;  // Prescaler value
      htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
      htim1.Init.Period = 999;    // Period value
      htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
      htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
      if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
      }

      sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
      sConfigOC.Pulse = 200;  // Duty cycle value for Channel 1 (20%)
      sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
      sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
      if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
      }

      HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim1);

}

void HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(TIM_HandleTypeDef* timHandle)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if(timHandle->Instance==TIM1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_MspPostInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_MspPostInit 0 */

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**TIM1 GPIO Configuration
    PA9     ------> TIM1_CH2
    PA8     ------> TIM1_CH1
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_8;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF1_TIM1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_MspPostInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_MspPostInit 1 */
  }

}


I see a lot of configuration, but I don't see you actually enable the timer counter. Try to enable the timer counter, see if it helps.

@Ilya I used HAL_TIM_PWM_Startit's not the right way to enbale timer ?

Ah. Sorry, didn't notice, you're right, it should be enough. Did you check timer registers? Did you enable timer clock? I can only see system clock and GPIO clock, but not timer clock enabled.

You only seem to configure PWM for TIM_CHANNEL_1. Don't you need to configure channel 2 as well?

Read out and check/post content of TIM and relevant GPIO registers. Often, the problem is that TIM1 is an Advanced Timer and needs TIMx_BDTR.MOE to be set; I don't use Cube and don't know if the above code sets it.
